# problem with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" with knex

Tags: node.js, typescript, knex.js

I'm new here and new to nodejs, knexjs and typescript. I'm working on a project kind of hard for me right now, but i'm tryong my best.
My problem here is that i keep getting

> [20/09/2021 14:48:17] [ERROR]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

While trying to retrieve data from a query, and i don't really understand why.
The principe is to do a restful API, and the part i'm looking for help is this one :
i'm doing an insertion in the table link, the insertion goes well, but i've got an error while trying to retrieve the generated entity at the end of the PostShortener method.
Im doing tests for that with insomnia.

there's the concerned code :

***for the table

```
    import Knex from "knex";
import Entity from "./Entity";
import Logger from "../logger/Logger";
import {FindOneByArgs, Join} from "./types";

export default class Table {

    private readonly knex: Knex;
    private readonly table: string;
    private readonly entity: () => Entity;
    private readonly joins: Array<Join>

    constructor(knex: Knex, table: string, entity: () => Entity, joins: Array<Join> = []) {
        this.knex = knex;
        this.table = table;
        this.entity = entity;
        this.joins = joins;
    }

    protected buildJoin(knex: Knex.QueryBuilder): Knex.QueryBuilder {
        this.joins.forEach(join =>
            knex.joinRaw(`${join.type || "INNER"} JOIN ${join.table} ON ${this.table}.${join.column} ${join.operator || "="} ${join.table}.${join.references || `id`}`)
        );

        return knex;
    }

    public findOneBy(...args: Array<FindOneByArgs>): Promise<Entity | void> {
        const request = this.knex(this.table)
            .select(`${this.table}.*`)
            .where(builder => args.forEach(arg => builder.where(arg.column, arg.operator || '=', arg.value)
            ))
            .limit(1);

        return this.buildJoin(request)
            .then(data => {
                console.log('data', data); // i get the data here
                return Entity.hydrate(data, this.entity) as Entity; // this one works for another request but doesn't seems to work for that post shortener
            })
            .catch(Logger.catch(`ESQL-FOB-${this.table}-`));
    }

    public findOneByid(id: number): Promise<Entity | void> {
        return this.findOneBy({column: `${this.table}.id`, value: id});
    }

    public insert(entity: Entity): Promise<Entity | void> {
        return this.knex(this.table)
            .insert(entity.toObject(), ['id'])
            .then(([id]) => this.findOneByid(id))
            .catch(Logger.catch(`ESQL-I-${this.table}`))
    }

}
```

*** for the entity

```
export default class Entity {

    public getId(): number {
        throw new Error('getId method wasn\'t implemented yet');
    }

    public setId(id: number): Entity {
        throw new Error('setId method wasn\'t implemented yet');
    }

    public static hydrate(data: Array<any>, entity: () => Entity): Array<Entity> | Entity | undefined {
        if (data.length === 0) return undefined;
        if (data.length === 1) { // @ts-ignore
            return (new entity()).hydrate(data[0])
        }
        // @ts-ignore
        return data.map(d => (new entity()).hydrate(d));
    }

    public hydrate(data: any): Entity {
        throw new Error('hydrate method wasn\'t implemented yet');
    }

    public toObject(): any {
        throw new Error('toObject method wasn\'t implemented yet');
    }

    public toJson(): string {
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    }
}
```

*** the link table

```
import Table from "../../../../class/orm/Table";
import Knex from "knex";
import LinkEntity from "./LinkEntity";

export default class LinkTable extends Table {

    constructor(knex: Knex) {
        super(
            knex,
            "link",
            // @ts-ignore
            LinkEntity,
            [
                {table: 'user', column: 'author_id'}
            ]
        );
    }

}
```

*** the link entity

```
import Entity from "../../../../class/orm/Entity";
import moment, {Moment} from "moment";
import {RawLinkEntity} from "../../types";
import UserEntity from "../../../user/db/UserEntity";
import {RawUserEntity} from "../../../user/types";

export default class LinkEntity extends Entity {

    private id: number | undefined;
    private link: string | undefined;
    private short: string | undefined;
    private keywords: string | undefined;
    private createdAt: Moment | undefined;
    private author: UserEntity | undefined;

    public getId(): number {
        return <number>this.id;
    }

    public getShort(): string {
        return <string>this.short;
    }

    public getLink(): string {
        return <string>this.link;
    }

    public getKeywords(): string {
        return <string>this.keywords;
    }

    public getCreatedAt(): moment.Moment {
        return <Moment>this.createdAt;
    }

    public getAuthor(): UserEntity {
        return <UserEntity>this.author;
    }

    public setId(id: number): LinkEntity {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public setShort(short: string): LinkEntity {
        this.short = short;

        return this;
    }

    public setLink(link: string): LinkEntity {
        this.link = link;

        return this;
    }

    public setKeywords(keywords: string): LinkEntity {
        this.keywords = keywords;
        return this;
    }

    public setCreatedAt(createdAt: Moment): LinkEntity {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        return this;
    }

    public setAuthor(author: UserEntity): LinkEntity {
        this.author = author;
        return this;
    }

    public hydrate(data: RawLinkEntity): LinkEntity {
        this.id = data.id;
        this.short = data.short;
        this.link = data.link;
        this.keywords = data.keywords;
        this.createdAt = moment(data.created_at);
        this.author = (new UserEntity()).hydrate(data.author as RawUserEntity);

        return this;
    }

    public toObject(): RawLinkEntity {
        return {
            id : this.getId(),
            short : this.getShort(),
            link : this.getLink(),
            keywords : this.getKeywords(),
            created_at : this.getCreatedAt().toDate(),
            author_id : this.getAuthor().getId()
        }
    }

}
```

and finally the post that is not retrieving the data at the end

```
import Api from "../../../class/hapi/Api";
import Joi from "joi";
import {Request, ResponseReturn} from "../../../class/hapi/types";
import {ResponseToolkit} from "@hapi/hapi";
import LinkEntity from "../db/link/LinkEntity";
import LinkTable from "../db/link/LinkTable";
import Boom from "@hapi/boom";
import {makeUid} from "../../../class/functions";
import UserEntity from "../../user/db/UserEntity";
import moment from "moment";

export default class PostShortener extends Api {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.path = '/shortener';
        this.method = 'POST';
        this.validate = {
            payload: Joi.object({
                short: Joi.string(),
                link: Joi.string().required(),
                keywords: Joi.string().required(),
                author: Joi.number().required()
            })
        };
        this.auth = {
            strategy: 'jwt-strategy'
        };
    }

    public run(request: Request, response: ResponseToolkit): ResponseReturn {
        // @ts-ignore
        const {short, link, keywords, author} = request.payload;
        const linkTable = new LinkTable(request.getKnex());

        const linkEntity = new LinkEntity()
            .setShort(short || makeUid(4))
            .setLink(link)
            .setKeywords(keywords)
            .setCreatedAt(moment())
            .setAuthor((new UserEntity()).setId(author));

        return linkTable
            .insert(linkEntity)
            .then(linkEntity => {
                console.log('linkEntity', linkEntity); // this one is always undefined
                if (!linkEntity) return Boom.internal('internal error');
                return linkTable.findOneByid(linkEntity.getId())
                    .then(linkEntity => {
                        if (!linkEntity) return Boom.internal('internal error');
                        return response.response(linkEntity.toJson());
                    });
            })
            .catch(() => Boom.internal('internal error'))
    }

}
```

ask me if you need any other informations, i'm not sure myself what you would need to know what's the issue
there's some ts-ignore here but they're working fine for another part of the API .

Note : i used debugging from knex and got thoses :

> bindings: [ 80, 1 ],
>
> __knexQueryUid: 'bzD-zUATyBDintj5OKzYb',
> sql: 'select `link`.* from `link` INNER JOIN user ON link.author_id =
> user.id where (`link`.`id` = ?) limit ?'

query is correct and informations are too. i'm really lost , i don't know why this isn't working.

**EDIT:**
I do not have any stack trace, how can i get it ?
i only have this as error message :

```
{
  method: 'select',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [ 83, 1 ],
  __knexQueryUid: '6lrsZc_A5fOKM-ymaSv2T',
  sql: 'select `link`.* from `link` INNER JOIN user ON link.author_id = user.id where (`link`.`id` = ?) limit ?'
}
[20/09/2021 16:35:07] [ERROR]: ESQL-FOB-link-
[20/09/2021 16:35:07] [ERROR]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

(with the debugging part of knex)

i did a console.trace(), maybe it will help

```
Trace
    at c:\Users\me\Desktop\tests\testsinsomnia\back\dist\class\orm\Table.js:30:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async exports.Manager.execute (c:\Users\me\Desktop\tests\testsinsomnia\back\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\toolkit.js:60:28)
    at async Object.internals.handler (c:\Users\me\Desktop\tests\testsinsomnia\back\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:46:20)
    at async exports.execute (c:\Users\me\Desktop\tests\testsinsomnia\back\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:31:20)
    at async Request._lifecycle (c:\Users\me\Desktop\tests\testsinsomnia\back\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:372:32)
    at async Request._execute (c:\Users\me\Desktop\tests\testsinsomnia\back\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:280:9)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at UserEntity.hydrate (c:\Users\me\Desktop\tests\testsinsomnia\back\dist\modules\user\db\UserEntity.js:157:24)
    at LinkEntity.hydrate (c:\Users\me\Desktop\tests\testsinsomnia\back\dist\modules\shortener\db\link\LinkEntity.js:58:52)
    at Function.hydrate (c:\Users\me\Desktop\tests\testsinsomnia\back\dist\class\orm\Entity.js:14:35)
    at c:\Users\me\Desktop\tests\testsinsomnia\back\dist\class\orm\Table.js:26:56
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async exports.Manager.execute (c:\Users\me\Desktop\tests\testsinsomnia\back\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\toolkit.js:60:28)
    at async Object.internals.handler (c:\Users\me\Desktop\tests\testsinsomnia\back\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:46:20)
    at async exports.execute (c:\Users\me\Desktop\tests\testsinsomnia\back\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:31:20)
    at async Request._lifecycle (c:\Users\me\Desktop\tests\testsinsomnia\back\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:372:32)
    at async Request._execute (c:\Users\me\Desktop\tests\testsinsomnia\back\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:280:9)
```

and i'm getting all the needed data in the Entity.hydrate(), i cloged them :

```
data [
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 85,
    short: 'P8He',
    link: 'https://google.com',
    keywords: 'test post shortener',
    created_at: 2021-09-20T14:41:11.000Z,
    author_id: 1
  }
]
```

**EDIT2:**
ok i've localized my problem :
when i get the informations from the database, with the join, i get one big package of data :

```
data [
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    short: 'Cwr5',
    link: 'https://google.com',
    keywords: 'test post shortener',
    created_at: 2021-09-21T09:15:33.000Z,
    author_id: 1,
    pseudo: 'test',
    password: '1234',
    email: 'aaaa@aaa.aa',
    address: 'aaaa',
    city: 'aaaaa',
    postal_code: '12345',
    country: 'aaaa',
    firstname: 'aaa',
    lastname: 'aaaa',
    gender: 'aaa',
    phone_number: '01234',
    birth_date: 2021-09-17T10:02:33.000Z,
    registration_at: 2021-09-17T10:02:33.000Z,
    last_connection_at: 2021-09-17T10:02:33.000Z,
    activated: 1,
    night_theme: 1,
    admin: 1,
    developer: 1,
    staff: 1,
    jwt_key: 'c8v5ZmdGAwhfPeM4HVem'
  }
]
```

the problem is, from author_id to the end, i should put it in a Type that have been built, RawUserEntity, containing all the informations of a User as an object
i don't know how to do that ...

**FINAL EDIT:**

i've solved the problem. knex has an option to nest results by table  :
.options({nestTables: true})

i just added it, and adapted my types, so i can retrieve needed informations.
all of that because i could have precisely locate my problem with the console.trace(). so it was hard for me (really a begginer) but i did!
thanks =)

Comment: The message you got means some code tried to refer to  `whateverObject.id` when `whateverObject` is null.  Your error message almost certainly came with a stack trace saying what line number the error occurred on. You should look at that stack trace to see where the problem occurred. If you can't figure it out, [edit] your question to show the stack trace.

Comment: i've solved the problem. knex has an option to nest results by table  :
`.options({nestTables: true})`

i just added it, and adapted my types, so i can retrieve needed informations.
all of that because i could have precisely locate my problem with the console.trace(). so it was hard for me (really a begginer) but i did!
thanks =)